# Is manipulating documentFragment in webWorker legal in principle(multithreading)?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker, documentfragment

1.main_thread and work_thread don't share anything(share nothing in common)

2.constructing domFragment to some level of structure(base on data) all in main_thread is a little time consuming,and can be  divide in to jobs for worker_thread.

however , i can find noway to pass in a DocumentFragment into work_thread

```
postMessage(fragment) // no way

postMessage({f:fragment}) // no way ,same reason above(serialization)

postMessage(fragment,[fragment]) // no way, type checking , must be a buffer type...
```

maybe this kind of optimizing is not worth the effort? any comments?

Comment: this time is not a wild assumption without root, now i am in a  web project which "server push" off the table(project half way to dead line), the web js quests web server per 5 second , polling 17000 data point to generate one/multiple chart,and other data to generate other chart,all contained in a master json data,the generated chart contains a lot of dom obj, so i think DOM constructing in worker thread would be a aid to the performance which have not founded the causing of the latency(UI in-responding). thanks for helping,thanks for watching either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [specification on W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#apis-available-to-workers) says, it is not possible to share any kind of a DOM API from your main thread with a worker thread.

Excerpt from the spec:

> The DOM APIs (Node objects, Document objects, etc) are not available to workers *[...]*

Since a DocumentFragment inherits at least from Node, it should be (nearly) impossible to send it to a webworker. I said nearly, because it might be possible to send it as a string (for example via innerHTML), but that means you would have to parse it in some way inside the worker thread or gather your information from that string. Personally, I don't think there is any smart way to do it.

A possible solution might be to pass the raw data as JSON to your worker thread, construct a string there an pass that string back.

Comment: which parsing the passed-Back string into DOM or Object still need a hell of work.

Comment: the main thread has too much burden.(rendering<my rendering means dom&css manipulating> and computing)